# Flows in Kotlin not collecting all values

Tags: kotlin

I'm doing some exercises to learn Flows in Kotlin, and I found some issues which I cannot understand.

1. When using a MutableStateFlow, in the next example it only prints the number 3. I would expect to print 0 to 3 instead. One could say that maybe is going too fast, or I should put a delay, but this seems to me a patch if such is the case, since if it is true that if sending MutableStateFlow data too fast makes it skip some values, then is something to consider every single time when using it.

   ```
    val flow = MutableStateFlow<Int>(0)

    fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {

        launch {
            flow.collect {
                println(it)
            }
        }

        (0..3).forEach {
            flow.emit(it)
        }
    }

    // Expected to print 0, 1, 2, 3
    // Printing only 3
   ```
2. Next, I tried to use a MutableSharedFlow instead, but it emits nothing at all, not even 3. Same code as above but replacing the flow with:

   ```
   val flow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
   ```

Comment: try adding a `Thread.sleep(1000)` in your `forEach` before emit. Then you should see all values getting printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MutableStateFlow cannot be used here because its behavior does not allow to get every value
so I used SharedFlow

**Example with SharedFlow:**

```
val flow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {

    val scope = // scope
    flow
        .onEach {
            println(it)
        }
        .launchIn(scope)

    (0..3).forEach {
        flow.emit(it)
    }
    // delay to wait for println
    launch {
        delay(10000)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but, if I am not using android and I need a "hot" flow, then what is the solution? a basic "flow" is by nature cold, while MutableStateFlow and MutableSharedFlow are hot flows.

Comment: @API_1024 Got you, changed my answer.